# Easiest way to bind property from view1 to view2

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**View1.xaml**

```
<TabControl x:Name="MainTab">
        <TabItem Header="1"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="2"></TabItem>
```

**View2.xaml**

```
<StatusBar>
        <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding ElementName=MainTab, Path=SelectedItem.Header, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StatusBar>
```

And the `Header` name of `TabItem` we can see on `StatusBar`, it works when both controls are in same view. I guess something is wrong with binding.

Comment: use a `viewmodel`

Comment: Use a ViewModel and bind both elements to the same property.